# How do I implement in tsx from tutorial?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The tutorial source: A Stateful Component - https://facebook.github.io/react/

This is my code:

```
interface Props {

}

interface State {
    secondsElapsed: number,
}


class Timer extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    private interval: number;

    getInitialState() {
        return { secondsElapsed: 0 };
    }
    tick() {
        this.setState({ secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1 });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Seconds Elapsed: {this.state.secondsElapsed}</div>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Timer />,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

In html, it returns `timer.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'secondsElapsed' of null`. Why is null of secondsElapsed?

What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React ES6-classes have no `getInitialState` method. This method have only components which was created by `React.createClass({})`

In React classes you can set state manually inside constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        secondsElapsed: 0
    };
}
```

[React docs about ES6-classes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes)